# Groovy: strange error with dynamic method invocation

Tags: dynamic, methods, groovy, invocation

The following is a program that dynamically calls all the `getXXX` methods on an object of `CLASS`, where the `CLASS`-name gets passed via command-line. **And it works just fine.**

```
// Program: callAllMethods.groovy

// Invoke this program as: groovy callAllMethods Date 

args.each { arg ->
    println "Methods of ${arg} ..."

    def code = """
        x = new ${arg}()
        x.class.methods.each { f ->
            if (f.name.startsWith("get")) {
                print "new ${arg}()." + f.name + ": " + f.invoke(x) 
                println ''

            }
        }  
    """
    evaluate("$code")
    println ''
}
```

However, when I try the simpler style of dynamic-method invocation (that does not use  `METHOD.invoke(OBJECT)` but rather `OBJECT."METHOD-NAME"()`), like so,

```
// Program: callAllMethods.groovy

// Invoke this program as: groovy callAllMethods Date 

args.each { arg ->
    println "Methods of ${arg} ..."

    def code = """
        x = new ${arg}()
        x.class.methods.each { f ->
            if (f.name.startsWith("get")) {
                result = x."${f.name}"()
                println "new ${arg}().${f.name}: ${result}" 
            }
        }  
    """
    evaluate("$code")
    println ''
}
```

... I get the following error:

```
$ groovy callGetMethods.groovy Date
Methods of Date ...
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: f for class: callGetMethods
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: f for class: callGetMethods
    at callGetMethods$_run_closure1.doCall(callGetMethods.groovy:13)
    at callGetMethods.run(callGetMethods.groovy:10)
```

I cannot understand why! Groovy version that I'm using:

```
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.1.3 JVM: 1.6.0_43 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because when you use the reflection based one (the `x.class.methods.each` one), you concatenate and generate the code upon GString evaluation, which resolves only one variable against the current scope, which is `arg`, and that is ok. If you print the code, it outputs a perfectly runnable Groovy code:

```
x = new Date()
x.class.methods.each { f ->
    if (f.name.startsWith("get")) {
        print "new Date()." + f.name + ": " + f.invoke(x) 
        println ''
    }
}
```

---

In your second version, the `GString` variables are resolved against the scope they were created, which is the script binding. So it tries to fetch the `f` variable from that scope, and not from the `code` variable. And that is why it crashes at the `${f}` variable.

If you change the `code` variable into a plain string (single quotes), it won't resolve the variable `arg`, and thus you will need to tweak a bit around it to create a new class from it. Even so, it will fail, unless you pass as argument `groovy callAllMethods java.util.Date`, which is not groovy (pun intended).

So, to use your code in that way, the GString shouldn't be resolved in declaration time, but rather at `evaluate()` time. Still, the `arg` variable needs to be resolved in declaration time, thus, you need to concat it. Here is the result:

```
args.each { arg ->
    println "Methods of ${arg} ..."

    def code = '''
        x = new '''+arg+'''()
        x.class.methods.each { m ->
            if (m.name.startsWith("get")) {
                result = x."${m.name}"()
                println "new '''+arg+'''().${m.name}: ${result}"
            }
        }  
    '''
    evaluate code
    println ''
}
```

Which, in my box (jdk7, groovy 2.1.3), outputs:

```
new Date().getDay: 0
new Date().getTimezoneOffset: 180
new Date().getDate: 2
new Date().getHours: 10
new Date().getMinutes: 39
new Date().getMonth: 5
new Date().getSeconds: 56
new Date().getTime: 1370180396136
new Date().getYear: 113
new Date().getClass: class java.util.Date
```

---

If you just want to output the properties from an object, may i suggest the `object.properties`?

```
args.each { arg ->
    println "Methods of ${arg} ..."

    def code = '''
        x = new '''+arg+'''()
        x.properties.each { 
            println "new '''+arg+'''().${it.key}: ${x[it.key]}"
        }  
    '''
    evaluate code
    println ''
}
```

It outputs a bit more stuff for `Date`, though :-).

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to do with scopes -- just didn't know where the heck to look in official documentation. Your statement *... the `GString` shouldn't be resolved in declaration time, but rather at `evaluate()` time* clarified it instantly! Thanks also for showing the simpler usage of `evaluate code`... not simpler, groovy usage rather (pun intended :-))